# Merging two Map<String,List>

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have two HashMaps where key is String and value is an ArrayList. I need to merge these two maps in such a way that if --

1. If key does not exist already, key should be mapped with value given.
2. If key is already present, I want the existing value to be merged with new value, i.e., existingList.addAll(newList).

initial code somewhat looks like --

for all keys of map check if

```
 if (map1.containsKey("key")){
 List l = map1.get ("key");
 l.addAll(map2.get("key"));
 }
 else{
 map1.put(map2);
 }
```

I do not care about duplicate elements here. Is there a clean way of doing this? I have read about merge method introduced in Java 8. But since the values are List type here I am looking for a more efficient and clean way.

Comment: I would suggest to just write it in exactly the way you described it. Then afterwards you can always refactor it.

Comment: Can you add the code of your first attempt? Based on this it will be much easier to discuss cleanliness and efficiency

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean with “*I do not care about duplicate elements here*”. Besides that, `merge` seems to be the way to go, i.e. `map2.forEach((k,v)->map1.merge(k, v, (l1,l2)->{ l1.addAll(l2); return l1; }));`

Comment: Edited for suggested changes.

Comment: @Holger I do not care about duplicates in the list, I meant. Thanks for your suggestion BTW. I would try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using java8's Map.merge()

```
//your two input maps
Map<String, List<String>> input1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<String>> input2 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<String>>[] arrr = new Map[]{input1,input2};

Map<String, List<String>> merged = new HashMap<>();
for(Map<String, List<String>> input:arrr){
  for(Entry<String, List<String>> e:input.entrySet()){
    merged.merge(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), (v1,v2)->{v1.addAll(v2);return v1;});
  }
}
```

This creates one Map instance as output (`merged`). I did not test this, so I'm not sure if the inner workings of `merge` cause `v1` to be `null` at some point.

Comment: Do not want to have a third map but merge one with the other. Thanks, will try to modify this.

Comment: Besides, nested for loops would not go too well.

Comment: @raghav the outer loop iterates exactly twice since you have 2 input maps. And since the keys might differ between those maps, you need to merge with both. So how is that not a good idea?

Comment: Not contesting the merit of your answer. Its just that people at my workplace are touchy about nested loops. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code helps. You should iterate one of the lists and add or update the other list.

```
public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>> merge(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>> list_1, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>> list_2) {
    //Iterate second hash map
    Iterator it = list_2.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        String key = (String) pair.getKey();
        ArrayList<Object> value = (ArrayList<Object>) pair.getValue();
        if(list_1.containsKey(key)){
            //UPDATE
            list_1.replace(key, value); //Replaces the entry for the specified key only if it is currently mapped to some value.
        } else {
            //ADD
            list_1.put(key, value);
        }
    }
    return list_1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will be much more readable if you switch from `Map<String, ArrayList>` to [guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)'s `Multimap`

Then merging can be done with `putAll`

```
multimap.putAll(secondMultimap);
```

Comment: putAll() is also possible with Java's Maps but will not putAll() replace the value if a key already exists?